# migrating from jira soap api to jira rest api: issues with getCustomFieldValues

Tags: java, groovy, jira, jira-rest-api

I am working on migrating some code from Jira Soap Api to Jira Rest API. I have a line of the legacy code that looks like:

`String estimationTypes = issue.getCustomFieldValues().find{it.customfieldId == SOME_STRING_VALUE_HERE}?.values.toString()`

The `issue`variable is of type `com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteIssue`and I am trying to migrate it and use an implementation of the new `Issue`interface (`com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue`), and so I am looking for an equivalent of the `getCustomFieldValues()`method that is defined as

```
public RemoteCustomFieldValue[] getCustomFieldValues() {
        return this.customFieldValues;
    }
```

But I did not find it. the Issue interface defines the `Object getCustomFieldValue(CustomField customField)`which is not the same. So how could I use a method equivalent to `getCustomFieldValues`?

I guess if I had a method like

`List<CustomField> getCustomFields()`then I would be able to create a method:  something like

```
public List<Object> getCustomFieldValues() {
   List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>()
   List<CustomField> customFields = getCustomFields()
   for(CustomField cs: customFields) {
      result.add(issue.getCustomFieldValue(cs))
   }
   return result       
}
```

My goal is to make the migration with the minimum possible impact on the legacy code. There I would like to be able to mimic the behavior of the legacy code as much as possible. Any help or indication is highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like `com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager` is the right for you - it provides several `List<CustomField> getCustomFields()` queries.

Comment: @xerx593 thank you. Is the CustomFieldManager a part a jira-java-rest-api? Is there a way to do it without using the java rest api and accessing the jira-rest-api endpoints directly?

Comment: @alainlompo, you may check this [link](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues) from atlassian documentation and use `soapui` to test it.

Comment: @Rao thank you: but this link is mostly about querying issues. I am more specifically trying to get custom field values

Comment: Am sure you should be able locate similar examples there.

Comment: @Rao, OK, thank you I will extend my searchs there and let you know

Comment: @alainlompo, ok. Basically just to let you know that it is possible to test the rest api without writing code. It would be more easy if you have the swagger definition so the request can be created easily, change the values and try it out.

Comment: @Rao, thanks. Yes I am aware of that. I have been testing the api using curl, soapui and it's working. I just need to find the way to do this specific thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and curling in one of the most interesting APIs I ever used, I find some very usefull informations on Atlassian knowledge base [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-retrieve-available-options-for-a-multi-select-customfield-via-jira-rest-api-815566715.html). The text is targeting a multi - select custom field but is usefull for other types of custom fields as well.

**It mentions clearly that JIRA's REST API doesn't provide a method to simply retrieve all the options available to a multi-option custom field**. The approach used here is therefore considered a workaround. So we can use

- The create issue meta api ([here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/?&_ga=1.100897729.1753852075.1468721151#api/2/issue-getCreateIssueMeta))
- Or the edit issue meta api ([here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/?&_ga=1.130088143.1753852075.1468721151#api/2/issue-getEditIssueMeta))

[image: Showing the custom field allowed values]

Following the two meta apis links, the parameters from the create meta api are simple but in the case of the edit meta api there is one request parameter called `overrideScreenSecurity`that is related to add-on users and a direct access to the add-ons market place from the web interface, but does is not relevant in my case and the default (false) value is fine for me.

From here I can parse the json to get the values